# ubuntu 18.04 network after cloud-init removal

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I installed new Ubuntu 18.04 on my home server and i noticed that `/etc/network/interfaces` file is empty. After searching on internet I found out that version 18.04 uses `cloud-init` package to init networking and other stuff. I removed cloud-init package and configured interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` for static IP but now after I reboot server it seems that networking is not configured before services startup because every service configured to listed on that interface fails to listen. After server is booted i have to manually run command *`service [name] start`*. How do I fix this?

**Interface config image**

[image: Interface config image]

Comment: something to do with systemd prio i reckon

Comment: Did you run `systemct list-unit-files | grep networking` to see if it's enabled?

Comment: ```systemctl list-unit-files | grep networking``` outputs nothing but ```systemctl list-unit-files | grep network``` outputs [this](https://i.imgur.com/Q7kaWL0.png).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu has [changed the tooling](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Network_configuration) behind its network configuration, and that's what you're running into now with your 18.04 system. The new system is [Netplan](https://netplan.io), and `/etc/network/interfaces` and the related `ifupdown` tools have been deprecated.

Since you removed cloud-init it's not really the problem here. You have two ways to move forward - you can either 1) configure Netplan with your static IP info; or 2) re-install the legacy `ifupdown` package and use it like you used to.

To configure Netplan, remove the config file that cloud-init probably left behind: 
`rm /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

And then create a new config file named something like `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml` and adapt one of the config file examples [found here](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan).